# Laplace transform of $u(t-5)t^2e^{-2t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

If t were equal to (t-5) I would use $\frac{n!}{(s-a)^{n+1}}$ which n is power of t and a is the power of $e^t$. However it is not. What should I do, can you give me a hint please?

Comment: Hint: ignore the step function and look at the Laplace transform of $t^2 e^{-2t}.$ Now use the property for transforming a function multiplied by a step function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use that the general form $u(t-c) g(t)$ has a Laplace transform of $e^{-cs} \mathcal{L}[g(t + c)]$. Then, in your case $g(t) = t^2 e^{-2t}$ and $c = 5$, so we simply need to find the Laplace transform of
$$
(t + 5)^2 e^{-2(t+5)} = e^{-10} (t + 5)^2 e^{-2t}.
$$
The constant $e^{-10}$ can be brought outside of the Laplace transform since it is a linear operator. Thus, we need to compute the following:
$$
\mathcal{L}[(t + 5)^2 e^{-2t}] = \mathcal{L}[t^2 e^{-2t}] + 10 \mathcal{L}[t e^{-2t}] + 25 \mathcal{L}[e^{-2t}]
$$
Each of these terms are common Laplace transforms that can be found on any Laplace transform table which gives us our answer of:
$$
\mathcal{L}[u(t-5) t^2 e^{-2t}] = e^{-5s} \cdot e^{-10} \bigg( \frac{2!}{(s+2)^3} + \frac{10 \cdot 1!}{(s + 2)^2} + \frac{25}{s+2} \bigg)
$$
After some simplification, we get
$$
\mathcal{L}[u(t-5) t^2 e^{-2t}] =\frac{25s^2 + 110s + 122}{(s+2)^3}  e^{-5(s + 2)} 
$$